# Mysql Join / Union issue

Tags: mysql, join, union

I am trying to create a report that pulls data from 2 tables: a & b.  The report is grouped by a.clock.  Most of the data for the report comes from a - that part is working fine.  a.clock links with b.userID.

The part i am struggling with is for one of the columns the data comes from b.  I need to total up the following for each a.clock grouping in the main report (this query works standalone)

```
 SELECT (
   SUM(
     TIME_TO_SEC(
       TIMEDIFF(
         CONCAT(b.endDate, ' ', b.outTime),
         CONCAT(b.startDate, ' ', b.inTime)
       )
     ) / 3600
   )
 ) AS 'Misc Hours' FROM b
```

In other words, i need to total the Misc Hours (in b) for each a.clock.  I thought maybe joining the b table was necessary but that didn't seem to work.  Any suggestions?

Here are the table definitions (sorry, verbose)

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `laborID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0=sched; 1=accepted; 2=complete; 3=authorize',
  `laborType` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Lookup',
  `hours` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `wage` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `laborDate` date NOT NULL,
  `ot` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `clock` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `setup` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ot2` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `wageOT1` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `wageOT2` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `inTime` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `outTime` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `startDateString` varchar(125) NOT NULL,
  `endDateString` varchar(125) NOT NULL,
  `authRequestDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `authRequestUser` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `authRequestReason` text NOT NULL,
  `authDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `authUser` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `authRequired` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `km` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `travelTime` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `actualInTime` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `actualOutTime` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `actualKm` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `actualTravelTime` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `intNotes` text,
  `extNotes` text,
  `billableReason` text,
  `billableHours` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `actualHours` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `overtime` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `followUpReason` text NOT NULL,
  `responseType` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `followUpType` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `billableDrop` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`laborID`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `laborDate` (`laborDate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;


CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `timecodeID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `inTime` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `outTime` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `startDateString` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  `endDateString` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  `startDate` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `endDate` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `comments` text NOT NULL,
  `multiDay` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`timecodeID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Can you provide the schema of your tables?

Comment: a.clock is varchar(15), b.userid is int(10). How do they link up as you said? Something is not clear for me here.

Comment: Yes, please explain how `a` and `b` link up. Some sample data would be helpful if you have it.

Comment: Each Labor & timecode record has a userID associated with it.  in the timecode table it's called userID, and in the labor table it's called clock.

Comment: Then, they should be of the same datatype. Not `VARCHAR` on one and `INT` on the other.

Comment: Your date and time columns should also not be `VARCHAR`. MySQL has a `DATE` dadatype and a `TIME` datatype that you can use.

Comment: @ypercube is right. You need to properly format your table structs so you can successfully get the information you want by joining the two tables and grouping on the ID in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you have multiple rows in each of the table then you will get larger sum  as each row in labor will join with each row in timecodes. So the idea is to have nested query group by clock and userid to get one row each as per the groupping

```
SELECT A.Clock, A.hours, B.'Misc Hours'
  FROM
     (
        SELECT labor.clock,
               SUM(hours) Hours
          FROM labor
         GROUP BY labor.clock
     ) A
 INNER JOIN 
     (
        SELECT  timecodes.userID,
                (SUM(
                     TIME_TO_SEC(
                          TIMEDIFF(
                               CONCAT(timecodes.endDate,' ',timecodes.outTime),
                               CONCAT(timecodes.startDate,' ',timecodes.inTime)
                          )
                      )/3600
                  )
                 ) AS 'Misc Hours'
         FROM timecodes
        GROUP BY timecodes.userID

) AS B ON A.Clock = B.UserId
```

Comment: I had to fix a couple typos but that was exactly what i needed - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT timecodes.userID,
       (SUM(
           TIME_TO_SEC(
                      TIMEDIFF(
                              CONCAT(timecodes.endDate,' ',timecodes.outTime),
                              CONCAT(timecodes.startDate,' ',timecodes.inTime)
                              )
                      )/3600
           )
       )
      AS 'Misc Hours'
FROM timecodes WHERE timecodes.userID=labor.clock GROUP BY labor.clock
```

Comment: Thanks i just attached a link to the schema

Comment: I don't think that query is returning the right data.  the 'misc hours' column seems way too high.  WHen i run:

    `SELECT timecodes.userID,(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(CONCAT(timecodes.endDate,' ',timecodes.outTime),CONCAT(timecodes.startDate,' ',timecodes.inTime)))/3600)) AS 'Misc Hours' FROM timecodes WHERE timecodes.userID=63`

I get a total of 324.5 hours.  When i run your script (which is something i tried before, i get 202125 hours for that same userID.

Comment: I updated the query now. If it throws any error on the type of the columns, modify the WHERE clause to CAST(timecodes.userID as VARCHAR)=labor.clock